# Select only 3 best ranked after rank() over

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I'd like to select the 3 best results of a rank() function for each partition

For instance, in this query :

```
SELECT id, rank() over (PARTITION BY year order by ...) as rank
FROM table1
GROUP BY year
```

I'd like to have 3 best ranked for every year.

I can manage that by making a new :

```
Select *
from ...
where rank <= 3
```

but then if I have some equalities, i'll get more than 3 row per year.

Do someone have an idea how to solve that ?

Comment: how do you define 'best results of a rank()'? what makes them best? please specify more columns

Comment: Is rank a number (like first, second, third) where there can be multiple people sharing third place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have not much information about your table and query structures, but as a generic solution I'd suggest to add `row_number() over (ORDER BY ... desc) as rn` and filter by it too with `where rn = 1` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452997/oracle-sql-how-to-get-distinct-rows-using-rank-or-dense-rank-or-row-number).

Comment: Well, in fact using row_number() INSTEAD of rank() solved my problem... I'm not very used to those sql functions yet... Thank you very much !

Comment: Oh, so THAT'S what you wanted to achieve... Please, feel free to specify more specific data (table names, columns...)